# Identifying mean term in stlm() arima function in R forecast package

Tags: r, arima

I'm trying to fit arima models using stlm function from forecast package. I need to identify arima order and mean term in the model, so that I can exclude models which are pure white noise. I can get the order of the fitted model using arimaorder() function but I'm unable to get the mean term from the model. How can I get the mean term from the model

For Generating white noise data

```
library(forecast)
white_noise <- arima.sim(model = list(order = c(0, 0, 0)), n = 100, mean = 0)
stlData <- ts(white_noise, frequency = 7)
fit <- stlm(stlData, robust = TRUE, method = c("arima"), approximation = FALSE, D=1)
arimaorder(fit$model)
fit$model
```

TIA

Comment: What do you mean by mean term? Perhaps the trend component?

Comment: I'm not sure if the output from `fit$model` -  'ARIMA(0,0,0) with zero mean' is same as trend.